# Can't add page break in google script to items created via for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a google form using a google script. I made a simple for-loop to create two items that will populate a drop down list. If a person picks item 1 it goes to page two and item 2 leads to page three. My problem is I get a **syntax error at line 14** when trying to create an if statement to do it.

I've tried removing the if-statement and it gives me the same error. I think pushing the `createChoice` items into an array causes it.

```
var targetNumber = form.addListItem();
var arr = [];
targetNumber.setTitle('How many targets?')
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  arr.push(targetNumber.createChoice(i));
  if(i == 1) {
    form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page2');
  } else {
    form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page3');
  }
}
targetNumber.setChoices(arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need a "for" loop? It is usually a good idea to use them, if you have an action to repeat multiple times. However, if the number of times you do it is rather small, I suggest you simply don't use them, as it can make for cleaner code. See below:

```js
var targetNumber = form.addListItem().setTitle('How many targets?');
var page2 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page 2');
// Add items to page2
var page3 = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page 3');
// Add items to page3
targetNumber.setChoices([
  targetNumber.createChoice(1, page2),
  targetNumber.createChoice(2, page3)
]);
```

The flow is the following:

1. Create your *ListItem*.
2. Create your second page and add items to it.
3. Create your third page and add items to it.
4. Set the choices to the *ListItem* you created in step 1.

#### Using a for-loop

```js
var targetNumber = form.addListItem().setTitle('How many targets?');
// Create pages
var pages = [];
for (var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PAGES; i++) {
  var page = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page ' + (i+2));
  // Add other items to the page
}
var choices = [];
for (var i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PAGES; i++) {
  choices.push(targetNumber.createChoice(i+1, pages[i]));
}
targetNumber.setChoices(choices);
```

Comment: I removed the number of items I currently need to just down to two. The original plan was to start with 10 items at first then add more in the future. I thought by automating that part would save me time in the future.

Comment: @papermachepaper That's definitely not a bad idea. Anyway, in case you may need to add more pages again in the future, I have added the for-loop version. Let me know if that works for you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you. Your help guided me to the right answer. I've added an edit to my original post to reflect your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
var targetNumber = form.addListItem();
var arr = [];
targetNumber.setTitle('How many targets?')
for (var i=1;i<3;i++){
  arr.push(targetNumber.createChoice(i));
    if(i==1){
      form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page2');
    }else{
      form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page3');
    }
}
targetNumber.setChoices(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves the syntax error but it's not following the page navigation rules. If I select 2 in the dropdown list, it goes to Page2 instead of Page3.